# Dart: alternatives for classic way to loop through arrays where index is needed

Tags: dart

I need to loop through list items and I need index, not value.

I know three options:

Classic:

```
for (final i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
```

With `asMap`:

```
for (final i in list.asMap().keys)
```

With `Iterable`:

```
for (final i in Iterable.generate(list.length)) {
```

Non-classic options look to be easier to read, write and less error prone.
How about performance? It seems both options produce iterable, so they should not create performance overhead. Is it correct assessment or I am missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Micro benchmark here (usual caveats apply) https://gist.github.com/jakemac53/16c782ed92f6bbceb98ad83cd257c760.

If your code is perf sensitive, use the "classic" for loop.

Comment: Even ignoring performance (which you shouldn't), the classical index loop is idiomatic and therefore very readable. If I see `for ... i = 0 .. < n.length ... i++` I know exactly what's going on - iterating the indices of `n`.
It's slightly verbose, but the recognition outweighs that. Trying to do something different makes the reader start wondering *why* you are doing something different, and if they are missing something important.
Use idiomatic code, because it tells the reader that they don't need to think any further. That's a big part of readability!

Comment: The problem is in deviations from standard: if `i=0` is intentionally replaced with `i=1`, reader will not catch it. It will take time for reader to figure out why 0 is missed.

Answer (score 1):

While existing alternatives for the classic way are not great from performance perspective, there is work in progress to introduce a better way to loop lists: https://github.com/dart-lang/collection/pull/259#discussion_r1090563595

For now you the extension will enable nice looping:

```
extension Indexes<T> on List<T> {
  Iterable<int> get indexes sync* {
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) yield i;
  }
}
```

Then we can write:

```
for (final i in list.indexes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [package:collection](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/IterableExtension/mapIndexed.html), you can get a `.mapIndexed` on an Iterable to give you both the item and the index of the item.

```
final result = someList.mapIndexed((n, e) => "item $n is $e");
```